# An $SU(3)$ isomorph in Clifford $G(5,0)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, intuition, mathematical-physics, quantum-groups, clifford-algebras

I am a computer scientist using the geometric (Clifford) algebras $G(n,0)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3 = \{0,1,-1\}$ to describe distributed computations. My question concerns $G(5,0)$ with generators $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$. It is a (novel) fact that the forms $vw+xyz$ in this algebra (dubbed "TauQuinions") form a 40-member five-fold group whose elements either form quaternion-isomorph triplets or are various versions of $-1$.

The 40 can be reduced to 8 by insisting that the bivector components $\{vw\}$ be chosen from $G(4,0) = \{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $(vw+vx+vy+wx+wy+xy)^2=0$. [This nilpotence may not be necessary, but this is the example I've used in my various calculations.] Then an instance of the tauquinion group is $T = \{ab+cde, ac-bde, ad+bce, -bc-ade, bd-ace, -cd-abe, 1-abcde, -e+abcd\}$, where $1-abcde$ is a $-1$, as is $-e+abcd$ (tho with a twist). Both square to $-1+abcde$, which is idempotent and plays the role of $+1$ in this group. [My calculations were carried out by a custom symbolic algebra system, so if your hand-checking disagrees, recall that $vw=-wv$ and $1+1+1=0$ here.]

I think that the tauquinion group $T$ is isomorphic to $SU(3)$ - the number of elements ($8 = 3^2-1$) is right, as is the quaternion connection - but all the (understandable) descriptions use 3x3 matrices and definitions over their i,j components, which is just not relevant (or relateable) to the tauquinion version of things.

So, I am looking for some other, hopefully straightforward, way to either establish that the tauquinion group is isomorphic to $SU(3)$, or not. A proof is welcome, as are suggestions.

Also, I've just learned that there are two versions of $SU(3)$ around, subC and subF, so if true, which one is $T$?

Comment: I've gone and TeXified your post; if anything looks out-of-sorts, please feel free to change it back.  Also, (1) you might find better answers at mathoverflow, and (2) when you say 'the number of elements' do you mean 'the dimension of the space' (or equivalently, 'group of generators')?  Generically, $SU(3)$ is an infinite group, and $SU(3)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ would be finite but certainly not of size 8...

Comment: By 'the number of elements' I mean the 'group of generators' ... (I think). I have an 8x8 multiplication table for T that forms a group, sure 'nuf. I wonder if you're forgetting the fact that Zed3 really shrinks things down. And there are some 13600 instances of T if one drops the nilpotence.

Comment: I guess my question (such as it is) would be 'what do you mean by $SU(3)$'?  That structure (canonically) is infinitely large, and the relations its usual eight generators obey aren't group relations per se.  If you mean $SU(3, \mathbb{Z}_3)$ then you'll have to be more specific what you mean by that group too, since on the surface 'unitary' only makes sense over $\mathbb{C}$, and more broadly I can't think of any matrix group over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ that only has 8 members.  It's still immensely unclear to me what you're asking here.

Comment: The group T showed up in a context [link](http://TauQuernions.org) where it and its precursor, TauQuernions - which are the same kind of thing, but in G(4,0) - are the _only_ operators (n>1) with this strange property of being isomorphic to the classical quaternions (and hence space-like) while simultaneously being irreversible (and hence time-like). The tauquinions fit physics-wise into the slot having to do with charge and magnetism. I have a draft of a paper about this, if you email me.

Comment: @MichaelManthey  Could you just consider explaining in set-notation what you mean by $SU(3)$ please?